# Как запустить php через консоль?

Tags: php

Прописал PAth

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь зайти, но ничего не происходит - просто мигает курсор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что должно произойти? `php.exe` это интерпретатор, он на вход должен получить php-файл  и выполнить его. Очевидно, в данном случае, интерпретатор ждет от вас команды.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим если у меня файл php.index находится вот здесь, E:\PHP_TEST как его запустить?

Comment: `Win+R` > `cmd` > `E:` > `cd php_test` > `php index.php`

Comment: @teran
так и сделал:

https://image.prntscr.com/image/3e2a58a707d6434eab3888befeea09df.jpeg

но винда походу все равно не видит интерпретатор

Comment: ну дак вы не то сделали. вам не переменную `%PHP%` надо было создавать. А взять переменную `PATH` и через `;` добавить туда путь к папке, где находится `php.exe` (без самого `exe`)

Comment: в вашем же случае, когда вы создали переменную `PHP`, в которой указали путь к `php.exe`, вы можете использовать ее следующим образом: `%PHP% index.php`, тогда система вместо `%PHP%` подставит путь к `php.exe`, а в случае с изменением `PATH` система будет пытаться найти вызываемый `php` во всех путях перечисленных в этой переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача запустить на выполнение экземпляр `php.exe` в произвольном месте системы. Когда вы находитесь в каталоге, и набираете команду `php.exe` система пытается запустить этот файл. Сначала она ищет его в текущей папке, затем в системной, а затем во всех папках указанных в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Вы написали, что прописали `Path`, но на самом деле сделали вы не это.
Переменная окружения `PATH`, содержит пути, где система производит поиск файлов. Это могут быть и файлы которые вы явно запускаете, и dll, которые пытаются найти другие программы и т.п.

Если вы отредактируете переменную `PATH` и добавите туда путь к папке с `php.exe`, то при выполнении команды `php` система найдет ее в данной директории и выполнит.
Переменная `PATH` есть как глобальная, так и для текущего пользователя. Что можно видеть в диалоговом окне настройки.

Поэтому в данном случае, вам необходимо отредактировать переменную `PATH` и добавить туда путь директории, содержащей интерпретатор (`E:\Program Files\OpenServer\modules\php\php-7.1-x64`). Директории разделяются `;`.

После того как сохраните изменения  и **перезапустите cmd.exe** вы сможете выполнять команду `php index.php` в любом месте файлов системы.

А из ваших скриншотов видно, что вы не `Path` отредактировали, а добавили новую переменную окружения `PHP`. При использовании переменные заключают в символы `%`, после чего система транслирует имя переменной в ее значение. Поэтому создав переменную `PHP`, указывающую на `php.exe` вы можете просто выполнять команду `%PHP%`, и, например, `%PHP% index.php`. Переменные используеются в различных местах, например, есть переменная `TMP` содержащая путь к папке со временными файлами. Команда `cd %TMP%` осуществит переход в данную директорию и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле вы все верно делаете, и php-интерпретатор тоже все верно делает. Суть в том, что он ожидает от вас поступления кода, который вы должны предоставить ему для выполнения. Вы можете сделать это как просто указав php-файл, который следует интерпретировать, так и напрямую передав код. Подробнее [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.usage.php).

Comment: Хорошо, допустим если у меня файл php.index находится вот  здесь, 
E:\PHP_TEST
как его запустить?

Comment: @Евгений заходим туда:  `cd E:\PHP_TEST` и после вызывает данный файл `php index.php`. или из любого места набрав в `php E:\PHP_TEST/index.php`